# Apache suddenly not working on vagrant

Tags: php, ubuntu, vagrant

I'm using windows 10 and have provisioned a Scotch Box VM using vagrant.
Everything was working fine up till yesterday, can't see through what I may have done or what could have been done to the system (maybe a windows 10 update?)

Thing is, I can start my VM normally, I can connect to it using ssh, and I can even run `php artisan tinker` and mess around with php (In that way, php is working).

But I **can't** see any of the websites that are in the public folder! The files still exist; Even if I type directly the IP address of the VM (http://192.168.33.10/)

Thinking that it may be a update I did to php 7 using this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php-7.0
```

Remove PHP 5 and install PHP 7:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge php5-fpm -y
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql -y
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove -y
```

found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705880/how-to-install-php-7)

I have tried doing a restart on apache, via command line, but it says its missing a php 5 library:

> vagrant@scotchbox:~$ sudo service apache2 restart
>   * Restarting web server apache2    [fail]
>   * The apache2 configtest failed.
>   Output of config test was:
>   apache2: Syntax error on line 141 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not > open configuration file /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: No such file > or directory
>   Action 'configtest' failed.
>   The Apache error log may have more information.

When I try to sudo apt-get install the missing library, it says that it was already installed and up to date, and can't find the log it says above.

I switched my environment, and everything works fine on linux (not inside vagrant, but running the source code directly with artisan serve)

All help apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the php5 modules, you should remove line 141 from your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file, the line would be `LoadModule ....`

Comment: Thanks! Will try that.